# How to get the dynamic part of a route from http.context in Play! Framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm using play2 Framework with Java have a route like this:

```
GET   /clients/:id          controllers.Clients.show(id: Long)
```

Additionally I use action composition by adding `@With(BeforeHandler.class)` to have a before-callback. Now I would like to inspect the id which is passed to the action already in my BeforeHandler. Actually it should be somewhere in the Http.Context which is passed to the call method of my BeforeHandler. Everything I can find there is a map with parsed static arguments like called controller, called action and the complete route. Also I found a queryString() map in `ctx._requestHeader().queryString()`.

Where can I find the dynamic part :id?

Answer (score 0):

with queryString you are trying to inspect something like
 `/clients?id=2`
and
`getQueryString("id")`
 will return 2

In your case,you should make a regex to find what you need, or something like that:

```
String[] paths = ctx.request().path().split("/");
Long id = Long.getLong(paths[2]);
```